# Parsing XML file in cprogram for particular element

Tags: c, libxml2, pugixml

currently im working in parsing xml by c and c++

im using pugixml library in c++ and libxml2 library in c for parsing xml

assume i have root element in xml as "configuration" and it have 4 child elements which are protocolversion,servername,daqlist and device.

Now i can get root element (configuration),by using this root i want to move its particular child (device) without moving one by one.

In C++ by using pugixml,we have following line to directly move from configuration to its child device,
    doc.child("Configuration").child("device").

In c by using libxml i just move one by one child as,
if cur node is root (configuration),then im using,
 cur= cur->children->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->next(for move to device from config)

i dont want to move by next next..
i want simple function to move from current to particular node in c by libxml..
could anyone please help to solve this issue..?

Answer (score 0):

The `->next->next...` approach assumes a fixed layout of nodes and is unreliable. I'd suggest that you:

- iterate the children until you find one with

  - `child->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE` and
  - `strcmp((char *)child->name, "device") == 0`
  - or `xmlStrcmp(child->name, BAD_CAST "device") == 0`
- use [XPath](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#XPath) to find nodes matching `/configuration/device`

Comment: i had serached in xpath but i dont know how it is useful for me when i try to movie from parrent node(Configuration) to its particular child node()Device without moving one by one child.. Could you tell me how to use xpath for that..with small example..??